# Asp.Net Core 3 Web API Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have been stock for 3days now with no possible solution online with this error

```
System.AggregateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ISecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[MyTrBox_WebAPI.Model.User]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.ISystemClock' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[MyTrBox_WebAPI.Model.User]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator`1[MyTrBox_WebAPI.Model.User]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.ISystemClock' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator`1[MyTrBox_WebAPI.Model.User]'.)
  Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DefaultServiceProviderFactory.CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection containerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ServiceFactoryAdapter`1.CreateServiceProvider(Object containerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at MyTrBox_WebAPI.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Biosec-PC-Samuel\Source\Repos\MyTrBox WebAPI\MyTrBox WebAPI\Program.cs:line 16

Inner Exception 1:
InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ISecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[MyTrBox_WebAPI.Model.User]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.ISystemClock' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[MyTrBox_WebAPI.Model.User]'.

Inner Exception 2:
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.ISystemClock' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[MyTrBox_WebAPI.Model.User]'.
```

this is the code I use to add identity in my startup

```
 var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<User>();
            builder = new IdentityBuilder(
                builder.UserType,
                typeof(UserRole),
                builder.Services);

            builder.AddRoles<UserRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<User>>();
```

User class:

```
public class User : IdentityUser<Guid>
    {
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; set; }
    }
```

UserRole class:

```
public class UserRole : IdentityRole<Guid>
    {
        public UserRole()
            : base() {

        } 
        public UserRole(string roleName)
            : base(roleName) {

        }
    }
```

I always run to the above error when I make any call to the API server
Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>MyTrBox_WebAPI</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="9.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: You're creating a lot of extra work for yourself by using `AddIdentityCore`. Is there a specific reason for doing that?

Comment: I have tried AddIdentity and I get IServiceCollection does not contain a definition for 'AddIdentity'

Comment: That should work, so I suggest looking into that more. Can you include the full error message for that in your question?

Comment: No detailed error it is a compiler error

Comment: I know, but it'll say something along the lines of "and no extension method ..." that might help diagnose your issue.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddIdentity' and no accessible extension method 'AddIdentity' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) MyTrBox WebAPI C:\Users\Biosec-PC-Samuel\Source\Repos\MyTrBox WebAPI\MyTrBox WebAPI\Startup.cs 87 Active

Comment: Can you also include the contents of your .csproj file in the question?

Comment: Just included it please help check

Comment: Do you share the full `csproj` content? There is no Identity related reference, I am wondering how you used `AddIdentityCore`?

Answer (score 2):

For customing asp.net core identity, you could follow steps below:

1. .csproj

   ```
   <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

   <PropertyGroup>
       <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
   </PropertyGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="3.0.0" />
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0" />
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.0.0">
       <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
       <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
       </PackageReference>
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="3.0.0" />
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.0.0" />
   </ItemGroup>

   </Project>
   ```
2. `CoreSecurityContext`

   ```
   public class CoreSecurityContext : IdentityDbContext<User, UserRole, Guid>
   {
       public CoreSecurityContext(DbContextOptions<CoreSecurityContext> options)
           : base(options)
       {
       }

       protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
       {
           base.OnModelCreating(builder);
           // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
           // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
           // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
       }
   }
   ```
3. `Startup.cs`

   ```
   services.AddDefaultIdentity<User>()
           .AddRoles<UserRole>()
           .AddEntityFrameworkStores<CoreSecurityContext>();
   ```