# Unable to resolve service for ISystemClock while attempting to activate SecurityStampValidator

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity

I try to add Identity to my web API, but get this error

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type >'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.ISystemClock' 
>   while attempting to activate >'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[WebAPI.Models.User>]'.

after adding Identity in Startup.cs, where I have this

```
services.AddIdentityCore<User>(options => { });
            new IdentityBuilder(typeof(User), typeof(IdentityRole), services)
                .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
                .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<User>>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>();

app.UseAuthentication();
```

The usermodel class is empty. Everything is loaded into the database.
What is missing? I appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `ISystemClock` is usually registered in the `AddAuthentication` call.  [You can see it in the sources here.](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/62351067ff4c1401556725b401478e648b66acdc/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src/AuthenticationServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L26)

Or, you could instead call `AddDefaultIdentity`, which in turn calls `AddAuthentication` itself.  [Sources here.](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/bfec2c14be1e65f7dd361a43950d4c848ad0cd35/src/Identity/UI/src/IdentityServiceCollectionUIExtensions.cs#L21-L63)

It's recommended you use one of those mechanisms rather than `AddIdentityCore`.  However, if you instead need to call `AddIdentityCore` for some reason, then you can register the clock yourself:

```
services.TryAddSingleton<ISystemClock, SystemClock>();
```

Though, you then may also run into other things to register that the aforementioned methods take care of.  See also [this question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58282348/asp-net-core-3-web-api-identity).

As for what it is - the `ISystemClock` interface is for getting the current time.  The `SystemClock` implementation gets the real time from the computer (by simply calling `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow`).  However, in testing, this allows a "fake clock" implementation to pass in different values of now, validating scenarios such as leap days, and other temporal business logic.  Such a pattern is often called "virtual clock" or "mock the clock".