# Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

When I inject SignInManager in ASP.NET Core 3.1, I get the exception message

*Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager'*

**My Account Controller**

```
private readonly UserManager<User> userManager;
private readonly SignInManager<User> signInManager;

public AccountController(UserManager<User> _userManager, SignInManager<User> _signInManager)
{
    this.userManager = _userManager;
    this.signInManager = _signInManager;
}
```

**My Startup.cs**

```
services.AddIdentityCore<User>(opt =>
{
    opt.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
})
.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
.AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User,IdentityRole>>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<HISDbContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));

services.AddDbContext<HISDbContext>(options =>            
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("HISConn"))
);

//services.AddScoped<UserManager<User>>();
```

**My User class**

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    //public string FirstName { get; set; }
    //public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `AddSignInManager` extension on `IdentityBuilder`.

Assuming that you've replaced `IdentityUser` with `User` elsewhere in your project, you can use `.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<User>>()` like below.

```
services.AddIdentityCore<User>(opt =>
{
    opt.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
})
.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
.AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User,IdentityRole>>()
.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<User>>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<HISDbContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

`AddSignInManager` [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.identitybuilderextensions.addsigninmanager?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: After Add SignInManager, i got this exception Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.ISystemClock' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator.     but this code work fine Startup.cs... services
        **    .AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<HISDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();**

Comment: Is the exception still talking about `SignInManager`? You probably need to add `.AddUserManager<UserManager<User>>()` as well

Comment: Sounds like you need to call `.AddAuthentication` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58344227/unable-to-resolve-service-for-isystemclock-while-attempting-to-activate-security)

Comment: Add UserManager<User> but still get same exception.

Comment: I reproduced your problem and it was fixed by adding `services.AddAuthentication()` to the top of `ConfigureServices`