# Error when adding identity migrations in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

When I run

```
dotnet ef migrations add IdentityInitial -p Data -s SignalRreactjs -c IdentityAppDbContext -o Identity/Migrations
```

I get this response back

> An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting
> services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error:
> Some services are not able to be constructed (E rror while validating
> the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ISecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped
> ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.Secu
> rityStampValidator`1[Data.Models.AppUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.ISystemClock' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Ide ntity.SecurityStampValidator`1[Data.Models.AppUser]'.) (Error while
> validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator Lifet
> ime: Scoped ImplementationType:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator`1[Data.Models.AppUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authenti cation.ISystemClock' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator`1[Data.Models.AppUser]'.)
> Unable to create an object of type 'IdentityAppDbContext'. For the
> different patterns supported at design time, see
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddDbContext<IdentityAppDbContext>(x =>
            {
                x.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("IdentityConnection"));
            });

            services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityAppDbContext>()
                .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<AppUser>>();

            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo {Title = "SignalRreactjs", Version = "v1"});
            });
        }
```

IdentityAppDbContext.cs

```
using Data.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Data.Identity
{
    public class IdentityAppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
    {
        public IdentityAppDbContext(DbContextOptions<IdentityAppDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
}
```

AppUser.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace Data.Models
{
    public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }

        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Data.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="5.0.4" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.4" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.4" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.4">
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      </PackageReference>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.4" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="6.8.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.8.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

SignalRreactjs.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.0-preview.2.21154.2">
          <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
          <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.6.3" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <Folder Include="Controllers" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\Data\Data.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Hi @lizardcoder,I think you could check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58344425/11398810).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using `AddIdentityCore()`, which (unlike `AddIdentity()` or `AddDefaultIdentity()`, all of which are confusing btw) doesn't contain a call to `AddAuthentication()`. Since `ISystemClock` is [added by](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/62351067ff4c1401556725b401478e648b66acdc/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src/AuthenticationServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L26) `AddAuthentication()`.

So you need to add a call yourself, preferably below `AddIdentityCore()`:

```csharp
services.AddAuthentication();
```

Possibly you'll also need to provide your authentication configuration, depending on your authentication requirements.

Alternatively, you can replace `AddIdentityCore()` with `AddIdentity()` or `AddDefaultIdentity()`. That way the problem won't occur, and you'll have authentication configured with Identity. But that configuration includes possibly annoying cookies and redirection, and it's generally only good when you're working on an MVC project (i.e. not web API).

Comment: Thank you I will try the solution out soon

Comment: @lizardcoder sure. :) If you'll have some additional questions, feel free to comment (or modify your question), and I can try to address them with an edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try registering `ISystemClock` in your `ConfigureServices` method in the startup class.

`services.TryAddSingleton<ISystemClock, SystemClock>();`

But it is not recommended. [Similar StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58344227/unable-to-resolve-service-for-isystemclock-while-attempting-to-activate-security)